# Aviary SDK frame issue

Tags: ios, ios7, aviary

I have updated the Aviary SDK for iOS 7 compatibility . Previously everything working good but in the iOS 7 I am having the following frame issue . **Cancel** button and **Done** buttons are cutting down at the edges and there is some gap from status bar and Aviary present modal view . Any ideas or help would be grateful .

[image]

Comment: Here's a customization option for editor, http://aviary.com/ios/customization, there's one method `[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setNavBarImage:image];` do check if you can re frame navigation bar there.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution for changing colour for "done" and "apply" button in "AFPhotoEditorController".

1. select & open "AviarySDKResources.bundle" from your project
2. open "AviarySDKColors.plist"
3. open "accentColor"
4. change value for key "hex" to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To fix frame dimensions I used

```
- (void)setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions
{
    [AFPhotoEditorCustomization setUsingIOS6SDK:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 7 they are using Border less navigation bar buttons with text highlight effect,No options to adjust the bar buttons,For Aviary suggesting bar buttons with example IOS 7 screens Layout in the style guide and you can achieve this effects by adjusting bar button color and opacity in Aviary SDK tool.

[image]

[image]